# Error: Dynamic link not supported when linking ocaml project under Lion 10.7

Tags: coq, ocamlbuild

I hope that's the right place to my question. Actually I'm coq user and I'm trying to implement a new tactic using ocaml under "Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4 ". I have installed all the libraries that I may need it. After compiling my ocaml file and when I try to import it in coq (I'm using Proofgenral and Aquamacs) I get this error Error: Dynamic link not supported. After a long search I find that's a problem in linking libraries but I haven't find how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [building a new coqtop](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/coqmktop.1.html) instead.

Comment: I tried it but I got this error : ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/local/lib/coq/kernel/byterun'